# nmcli does not show any devices

Tags: arch-linux, wifi, networkmanager, iwlwifi

I have a fresh install of Arch Linux on a Lenovo laptop.  I installed NetworkManager, but when I run `nmcli d`  I only see the loopback device.  The same result is shown when running `ip link`.
Both the `NetworkManager` and `wpa_supplicant` services are started and running.  Currently I am not able to use Wifi and NetworkManager does not show the device.
Running `lpsci -k` yields

> Network controller: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP PCH CNVI WiFi (Rev 30)
> Subsystem Intel Corporation Wi-fi 6
> Kernel Modules iwlwifi

How do I get NetworkManager to recognize this device?

Comment: No "Kernel driver in use" line in the output of `lspci` suggests that the `iwlwifi` module isn't loaded. You may verify this with `lsmod | grep iwlwifi`, try loading it with `modprobe iwlwifi` (as root), search the system logs (`journalctl`) for messages relating to your card, which may give you a hint on why the driver is not loaded on boot, and double-check that the module is not blacklisted in `/etc/modprobe.d/` or in the kernel command line.

Comment: There was nothing in `/etc/modprobe.d/`, `lsmod | grep iwlwifi' yields
```iwlwifi  450560 0
cfg80211  1048576 1 iwlwifi```
There were no errors after running `modprobe iwlwifi`
`journalctl` shows Direct firmware load for iwlwifi failed with error -2 and no suitable firmware found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to install the package `linux-firmware` and reboot the laptop
Once that was done, I was able to see all available networks and utilize Wifi